# Взаимодействие PHP с JQuery (и JavaScript)

Tags: jquery, javascript, php

Добрый день! Веб-программирование начал изучать относительно недавно. За это время удалось изучить неплохо PHP, HTML, CSS, немного Javascript и самую малость JQuery. При практическом программировании сайтов столкнулся с потребностью в динамических штучках для сайта, которые бы работали без перезагрузки страницы. Как известно этого нельзя добиться средствами PHP. Потому обратил свой взор к JavaScript и JQuery.

Расскажите немного про взаимодействие PHP с JQuery и JavaScript. Каким образом происходит обмен данными, если такая потребность возникает. Например есть элемент "лайк"(сердечко) которое отмечает симпатию читателю к статье, он ее щелкает и срабатывает JQuery-код - без обновления страницы должно прибавиться значение нового "лайка", потом это увеличенное на одно значение надо добавить в базу данных, тоесть средствами PHP записать в Mysql. Как такие вещи реализуются? Расскажите...

Смотрел эту статью [PHP библиотека для jQuery](http://anton.shevchuk.name/php/php-library-for-jquery/) и многое не понял. Доступным языком объясните, как идет связка фрейворка JQuery или даже только чистого JavaScript с PHP. Буду благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Технология называется AJAX.

Comment: Ну в теории про это я слышал, что AJAX. А как на практике ее использовать на моем примере или аналогичных задачах? Приведите что ли пример... или укажите на какую-то хорошую ссылку, где идет прямое взаимодействие данных между PHP и JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё очень просто. При помощи [AJAX](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) ([$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) в jQuery или [XMLHttpRequest](http://xmlhttprequest.ru/) в чистом JS) на сервер отправляется запрос. При этом страница не перезагружается. С точки зрения сервера запрос абсолютно аналогичен запросам, отправляемым при переходах по ссылкам или при вводе адреса в адресную строку. Вот пример на jQuery:

На клиенте:

```
$.ajax(
    type: 'GET',                   // тип запроса
    url: 'test.php',               // отправляем запрос на страницу test.php
    data: { name: 'Ivan' })        // данные, которые будут переданы с запросом
    .done(function(data) {         // объявляем обработчик для принятых данных
        alert(data);
    })
    .fail(function() {             // объявляем обработчик для ошибок
        alert('error');
    }
```

На сервере (test.php):

```
echo 'Hello, ' . $_GET['name']
```

При запуске AJAX-запроса, будет отправлен фоновый запрос `test.php?name=Ivan`, получен ответ (`'Hello, Ivan'`), который будет передан в обработчик `done`.

На чистом JS код выглядел бы немного более громоздко:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = 'name=Ivan'
xhr.open('GET', 'test.php?' + params, true);       // последний параметр - делать ли запрос асинхронным. Если запрос не асинхронный, он подвесит страницу до тех пор, пока не придёт ответ
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {                     // запрос завершён
        if (xhr.status == 200) {                   // код 200 - успешно
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            alert('error');
        }
    }
};
xhr.send(null);                                    // в качестве параметра передаются данные, посылаемые на сервер. Для GET-запросов параметр равен null, для POST-запросов - данным, которые нужно передать на сервер.
```

Таким образом, с сервера можно получать любые данные. Если данные - часть HTML-разметки, их передают в чистом виде. Если же данные имеют вид каких-либо объектов, то их передают на клиент в виде [JSON](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Ассоциативный массив PHP с любой степенью вложенности можно легко преобразовать в JSON функцией [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php). На клиенте нужно преобразовать принятую строку в объект. Это делается функцией [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: Спасибо за хороший и содержательный ответ. Вопрос только один почему написано у вас "на клиенте" и "на сервере", как будто это выполняется на разных компьютерах? Хотя понятно, что JavaScript выполняется на локальном компьютере, а PHP на сервере. Тем не менее весь этот код (и JS и PHP код) может быть умещен в один php файл, насколько я понял. Так?

Comment: Не может быть умещен в один файл. По крайней мере не в файл test.php из примера.

Следуя best-practice, js код лучше всего держать в файлах с расширением .js и подключать их в html через `<script type="text/javascript" src="/uri/to/file.js"></script>`

"На клиенте" означает, что код будет запускаться на клиенте. Каким образом он туда попадет - принципиальной разницы нет. Можно даже просто скопировать в консоль (в хроме по F12 открывается) и запустить  - тоже сработает.